# How to access a variable value in an environmental array variable in Thunder Client?

Tags: vscode-extensions, thunderclient

In one of my GET requests, I store the JSON response into an Environmental Variable Array.
I cannot seem to access the individual values in that array.  Is this supported or am I just not accessing them properly?

[My Environment Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUJrH.png)

```
[Environment Variables Tab]

Variable Name    |    Value
-----------------------------------  
myJsonArray      |   ["value1","value2","value3"]
```

[Using entire Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0ggj.png)

```
This picture just shows that Thunder client recognizes the variable myJsonArray as it's text is green.
{{baseURL}}route/{{myJsonArray}}
```

[Trying to access individual values in array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7odlx.png)

```
This picture shows that Thunder client does NOT recognize the attempt to access array element 2 via myJsonArray[2], as it's text is grey.
{{baseURL}}route/{{myJsonArray[2]}}
```

[Result of trying with square brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7vPp.png)

```
This picture shows the console output when trying to use the above array element.
Request Url: https://10.20.30.40/sidecar/route/%7B%7BmyJsonArray[2]%7D%7D
```

I also tried `myArray.[2]`.

Comment: Please  share all text details in text form, not hidden in screenshots

Comment: Edited with some text and descriptions.  I thought the pictures would show up without clicking links.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Thunder Client does not handle arrays natively. I have a similar problem using `tc.getVar()` to retrieve a boolean value. It turns out I need to make boolean conversion manually, something like `var myVar = tc.getVar("var_name") === "true"`.

For your use case, the simplest method I could think of is to store the actual array element needed in a separate var. (I do not understand why you put the entire array into URL. But for accessing individual values in array, this method should work.)

Otherwise, you may leverage `JSON.parse()` to parse the array from a string with custom filters.

Ref: https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/blob/master/docs/filters.md